# Three.js: draw a octahedron

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to draw a Octahedron,but the shape of the result is below expectation.I dont know the reason and next step I want to draw a Dodecahedron, any suggestions?[The result of the Octahedron](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKE2X.png)

My code:

```
var mesh, renderer, scene, camera, controls;

init();
animate();

function init() {

// renderer
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

// scene
scene = new THREE.Scene();

// camera
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40, window.innerWidth / 
window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
camera.position.set(20, 20, 20);

// controls
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);

// ambient
scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0x222222));

// light
var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
light.position.set(20, 20, 0);
scene.add(light);

// axes
scene.add(new THREE.AxisHelper(20));

// geometry
//var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(5, 12, 8);
var vertices = [
                0.5,0,0, 0,0.3,0, -0.5,0,0, 0,-0.3,0, 0,0,0.3, 0,0,-0.3
            ];
            var faces = [
                0,1,4, 1,2,4, 2,3,4, 3,0,4, 0,1,5, 1,2,5, 2,3,5, 3,0,5
            ];
var geometry = new THREE.PolyhedronGeometry(vertices, faces, 5, 1);
// material
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0x00ffff,
    shading: THREE.FlatShading,
    wireframe:true,
    transparent: true,
    opacity: 0.7,
});

// mesh
mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(mesh);

}

function animate() {

requestAnimationFrame(animate);

//controls.update();

renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
var geometry = new THREE.OctahedronGeometry( 5, 0 ); // or DodecahedronGeometry
```

Read and understand the source code of `OctahedronGeometry.js` if you want to use `PolyhedronGeometry` directly.

If `wireframe` is true, use `MeshBasicMaterial`, instead.

three.js r.85

Comment: What if want to create a octahedronGeometry with differnt length with x,  y, z?

Comment: Do you mean a non-regular polygon? If so, you can use `PolyhedronGeometry`, but you have to comment out the line `appplyRadius( radius );`, which is misspelled, actually.

Comment: Comment out the line applyRadius(radius)  in polyhedronGeometry.js is not work, why~

Comment: I do not have sufficient information to answer that question. Step through with the debugger. Make a new post if you need more help.